# RSpec Stub doesn't cover multiple nested Describe blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stubbing

I have a test suite structured as follows:

```
describe ... do
  [list of dates].each do
    describe
      before(:all) do
        base_date = ...
      end
      describe ... do
        [list of times].each do
          describe ... do
            before(:all) do
              base_time = base_date + ...
              DateTime.stub!(:now).and_return(base_time)
            end
            describe ... do
              <test using records within date-time range based on base_time>
            end
            describe ... do
              <another test using records within date-time range based on base_time>
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The first test has DateTime(now) == base_time, but the second test as DateTime(now) == my computer's date-time, indicating that the stub is no longer in effect.  Moving the `stub!` call into each `describe` loop resolves the problem, but I would like to understand why it doesn't work as written.

Comment: what if you replace your `before(:all)` with a `before(:each)`

Answer (score 1):

The reason lies probably elsewhere, stubs work fine with multiple nested describe blocks. Maybe :all vs :each is the problem: `before(:all)` is executed once before all describe blocks are executed, while `before(:each)` is executed each time before a describe block is executed.

Or maybe it has something to do with stubbing DateTime, have you tried

```
DateTime.any_instance.stub(:now).and_return(base_time)
```